# How to take data from a csv and populate an array with it In C

Tags: c, csv, cs50, strtok

Im writing a program that is meant to populate an array from a csv of crimes with their minimum and maximum sentences in months and populate a structure i created with that information so i can strcomp to that array with the input given and tell them what they're facing. This is what I have and its returning the same line over and over.

```
// C program for the above approach
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
  
  
typedef struct
{
    string crime_name;
    int minsent;
    int maxsent;
}
crimes;

crimes crime[40];
  
// Driver Code
int main()
{
    // Substitute the full file path
    // for the string file_path
    FILE* fp = fopen("crimes.csv", "r");
  
    if (!fp)
        printf("Can't open file\n");
  
    else {
        // Here we have taken size of
        // array 1024 you can modify it
        char buffer[1024];
  
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
  
        while (fgets(buffer,1024, fp)) {
              
  
            // To avoid printing of column
            // names in file can be changed
            // according to need
        //    if (row == 1)
            //    continue;
  
            // Splitting the data
  
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                column = 0;
                row = i; 
                char* value = strtok(buffer, ",");
                {
                    // Column 1
                    if (column == 0) 
                    {
                        printf("Crime :");
                   
                        crime[i].crime_name = value;
                  
                        column++;
                        value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
                        printf("%s ", crime[i].crime_name);
                    }
  
                    // Column 2
                    if (column == 1) 
                    {
                        printf("\tminimum sentence: ");
                        int min = atoi(value);
                        value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
                        crime[i].minsent = min;
                        column++;
                        printf("%i ", crime[i].minsent);
                        printf(" month(s)");
                    }
  
                    // Column 3
                    if (column == 2) 
                    {
                        printf("\tmaximum sentence: ");
                        int max = atoi(value);
                        value = strtok(NULL, ", ");

                        crime[i].maxsent = max;
                        column++;
                        printf("%i ", crime[i].maxsent);
                        printf(" month(s)");
                    }
                
                //    value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
  
                   // printf("%s", value);
                  //  value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
                    printf("\n");
                
            //    return 0;
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        // Close the file
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my csv file.

```
assault and battery , 0 , 12
aggravated assault , 0 , 12
domestic violence , 0 , 2
domestic battery , 0 , 12
illegal entry , 0 , 24
child abuse, 0 , 60
contributing to the delinquency of a minor , 0 , 3
insurance fraud , 0 , 48
1st degree murder , 240 , 960 
2nd degree murder , 180 , 960
3rd degree murder , 120 , 180
manslaughter , 10 , 180
arson , 12 , 240
money laundering , 0 , 240
disorderly conduct , 0 , 3
stalking , 0 , 12
prostitution , 0 , 60
Fraud , 0 , 240f
hit and run , 0 , 180
DUI , 1 , 60
Driving Under Influence , 1 , 60
selling alcohol to a minor , 0 , 12
public intoxication , 0 , 3
credit card fraud , 12 , 60 
Retail Fraud , 0 , 60
Larceny , 0 , 60
Shoplifting , 0 , 12
Reckless driving , 0 , 3
Driving with suspended license , 0 , 3
indecent exposure , 0 ,  12
```

Comment: The second argument (`delim`)  of `strtok` is a set of bytes that are used to delimit the fields, not a delimiter string. `", "` means `','` **or** `' '`. I suggest to use `","` only and to strip leading or trailing spaces separately if necessary. You have to call `strtok` for every field.

Comment: The lines `if (column == 0)`, `if (column == 1)`, `if (column == 2)` are redundant, as they will always be true.

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  You read one line, and then you iterate over that line 30 times.  What is the purpose of the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could completely remove your `for` loop. Your `while` loop reads every line till the end of your file.
Once you remove it you could try incrementing `row` manually at the end of your `while` loop, and replacing `i` with the value of `row`.